# My Android device got the wrong size, how to fix it? Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, size, scale, ionic4

When I compile my ionic project, and run it on ionic LAB or on an android device, there is always a wrong size. On IOS it fits perfectly but on Android it does not. Does anyone know how to scale it? Or resize it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHttl.png)

Comment: try to share also the code you already made

Comment: which script do you want to see? I don't know where to scale the android view.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like its an issue with the app.

Android uses different styles than IOS.

If you want it to mirror the IOS style throughout then you should add `mode="ios"` to every component (all the way down).

You should be able to tap and hold and scroll the tabs list on the android version to see the rest. I haven't looked it up exactly but if that doesn't work there is a setting to enable scroll functionality, check the docs.

Comment: allright, so there's no other way to scale the view? The view is really shitty.

Comment: yes you can [style it](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment-button#css-custom-properties) like any other component, but android users are used to that style and interaction so it might not actually improve things for your users.

Comment: yeah i know, but i dont know how to change the size of the segment, because the width is way to much. As you can see in the picture added. The button „Young Researcher“ for example.